# Simple Assignment Statement in Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
xn=input()
c=input()

xn1 = .5(xn+(c/xn))

print(str(xn1))
```

I can't seem to get this code to run. I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "eq.py", line 3, in <module>
  xn1 = .5(xn+(c/xn))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I've looked up a number of other assignment statements in Python, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this one. I also tried casting all the variables as floats.

Comment: do you mean xn1 = .5 * (xn +(c/xn))?

Comment: Unlike in math, concatenation is not multiplication in Python. `.5(whatever)` tries to treat `.5` as a function, rather than performing `.5*whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke .5 as if it were a function. Change the line:

```
xn1 = .5*(xn+(c/xn))
```

Example here: https://repl.it/F55K